# add a new dataframe based on multiple condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Hi I have data like this:

for example

```
id        genre    total_play
1         pop      20
1         rock     30
1         jazz     60
2         pop      60
2         country  30
2         rock     25
3         latin    25
3         kpop     25
3         folk     10
```

I want to create a new column based on the following rules:

- If a user listens to jazz music for more than 30% of the total play it will be labeled with category A
- If a user listens to pop music for more than 40% of the total play it will be labeled with category B
- Other than that then C

and will be like this:

```
id   tendency
1    A
2    B
3    C
```

Thanks before :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try pivot the table to calculate the total plays, then use `np.select`:

```
plays  = df.pivot_table('total_play','id','genre',fill_value=0)
totals = plays.sum(1)

pd.Series(np.select([plays['jazz']>totals*0.3, plays['pop'] > totals*0.4],['A','B'],'C'),
          index=plays.index)
```

Output:

```
id
1    A
2    B
3    C
dtype: object
```